# Password length validation never passes with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt-ruby

I'm trying to add a length validation to `password`, but it always errors out with 'Password is too short'.

```
a = Artist.new(artist_name: 'Dylan', email: 'dylan@example.com', password: 'notshort')
p a.errors.full_messages  # ["Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]
a = Artist.new(artist_name: 'Dylan', email: 'dylan@example.com', password: 'short')
p a.errors.full_messages  # ["Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]
```

In the model I have

```
has_secure_password
validates_length_of :password, minimum: 6
```

If I change the validation to

```
validates_length_of :password, minimum: 6, allow_blank: true
```

The `notshort` password passes, but so does `short`.

Comment: I can't replicate. `validates_length_of :password, minimum: 6` is causing `short` to error but succeeds with `notshort`.  I don't have bcrypt installed so I didn't run it with `has_secure_password`.  (Although `allow_blank: true` is causing them both to pass....weird)

Comment: that looks like a bug to me. what version of rails are you using?

Comment: Using Rails 4.1.4 … it does seem like a bug to me too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Bcrypt, too. This seems to work for me:

```
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 20 }, on: :create
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `validates_length_of`, try just using `validates` like this:

`validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }`

Comment: Dang. Well, the issue where having `allow_blank: true` and `minimum: 6` both on at the same time doesn't make sense to me from a logic standpoint so getting a weird result like that doesn't surprise me (why would you not allow short passwords, but then allow blank passwords?).

As far as the `validates_length_of` issue, I think the problem may have to do with using the `has_secure_password method` before it. Looking at the API, it apparently needs your class to also have a `:password_digest` attribute.

I would comment out the `has_secure_password` line and see if the length validation works.